# Converting array into multidimensional array in PHP when result is send from Oracle

Tags: php, arrays, oracle, multidimensional-array, fetch

Here is example how my array should look like:

```
$library = array(
    'book' => array(
        array(
            'authorFirst' => 'Mark',
            'authorLast' => 'Twain',
            'title' => 'The Innocents Abroad'
        ),
        array(
            'authorFirst' => 'Charles',
            'authorLast' => 'Dickens',
            'title' => 'Oliver Twist'
        )
    )
);
```

When I get results from oracle database:

```
$row = oci_fetch_array($refcur, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
```

But when I execute my code I only get one row.
For example: `<books><book></book><name></name></books>`

But I want all rows to be shown in xml.

EDIT:
This is my class for converting array to xml:

```
  public static function toXml($data, $rootNodeName = 'data', &$xml=null)
    {
        // turn off compatibility mode as simple xml throws a wobbly if you don't.
        if (ini_get('zend.ze1_compatibility_mode') == 1)
        {
            ini_set ('zend.ze1_compatibility_mode', 0);
        }

        if (is_null($xml))
        {
            $xml = simplexml_load_string("<".key($data)."/>");
        }

        // loop through the data passed in.
        foreach($data as $key => $value)
        {
            // if numeric key, assume array of rootNodeName elements
            if (is_numeric($key))
            {
                $key = $rootNodeName;
            }

            // delete any char not allowed in XML element names
            $key = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\-\_\.\:]/i', '', $key);

            // if there is another array found recrusively call this function
            if (is_array($value))
            {
                // create a new node unless this is an array of elements
                $node = ArrayToXML::isAssoc($value) ? $xml->addChild($key) : $xml;

                // recrusive call - pass $key as the new rootNodeName
                ArrayToXML::toXml($value, $key, $node);
            }
            else
            {
                // add single node.
                $value = htmlentities($value);
                $xml->addChild($key,$value);
            }

        }
        // pass back as string. or simple xml object if you want!
        return $xml->asXML();
    }

    // determine if a variable is an associative array
    public static function isAssoc( $array ) {
        return (is_array($array) && 0 !== count(array_diff_key($array, array_keys(array_keys($array)))));
    }
}
?>
```

Now with below responde I have tried problem is I get following output: `<book>...</book>` tags after each row.. then I tried 3 dimensional array now I get: `<book><book>...</book></book>` on the proper place but I have 2 of them.
This is the line where I have determine which is root on that array and that's why I get this output. But don't know how to change it : `$xml = simplexml_load_string("<".key($data)."/>");`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oci_fetch_array()` will always return a single row, you need to call it until there are no more rows to fetch in order to get all of them:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($refcur, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
{
    $library['book'][] = $row;
}
```